# inheritance: accessing array from super class to search it

Tags: java, inheritance

I have a superclass `Trail` that populates an array `myList[]`. I want a subclass `TrailSearch` to access `myList[]` and search it. How can i do this? I know i could simply pass the array to the `TrailSearch` class as an argument but i'm trying to get to grips with inheritance so i thought i try it the hard way but i need some tips.

```
PSEUDO CODE

class Main{

 new Trail trailObject

 new TrailSearch tsearchObject

 tsearchObject.methodSearchMyList()

}


class Trail{

constructor Trail(){}

   methodPopulateMyList(){
      // populate myList[]    }

}


class TrailSearch extends Trail{

constructor TrailSearch(){}

   methodSearchMyList(){
      // search myList[]    } 

}
```

that's more or less how i would approach it but what are the rules to make this inheritance idea work?

Comment: What you've written above is not Java. Perhaps you could write something that is Java (ie that a compiler will accept), and edit your question to show that instead. That would give us a clearer question to answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As long as the `myList[]` array is not declared `private` your subclass can access it directly.

Comment: thanks! indeed you are right. When i called the method from class Main i was missing a crucial element: I didn't reference myList to the superclass, thinking that i could call it by its name alone. It works perfectly fine if if do this: tsearchObject.methodSearchMyList(trialObject.myList)

Answer (score 2):

Inheritance is the wrong way to solve this problem, and this is the wrong problem to use if you are trying to get to grips with inheritance.  TrailSearch is **not** a Trail so shouldn't inherit from it.

A better solution to this problem is the visitor pattern: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visitor_pattern

Also see 
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/27db6csx%28v=vs.80%29.aspx for a brief explanation of the "Is A" relationship which implies inheritance.

Comment: I totally agree with this answer. My response is from a more abstract point of view ;)

Comment: thanks for the link to the "Is A" relationship document. Very useful! I'm sure you're right about inheritance not being the right way to think about this problem but as i stated my goal was to learn about inheritance as i kept getting runtime errors. Good to point it out nevertheless.

Comment: @Baba - I'd say that getting to grips with the theory of inheritance is probably more important that getting to grips with the implementation. But I understand that different people have different priorities and short term goals. Glad I could be of some help, and good luck :)

Answer (score 0):

Try to define myList[] as a **protected** variable in class Trail, then you can access the variable from your subclass also

Answer (score 0):

In java, for each field and method, you must declare the visibility. This will determine who can access this field or this method. Visibility is declared with a keyword, which is one of these :

- `public` : The field or method can be accessed from everywhere
- `private` : Only the class where the field / method is declared can access it
- `protected` : Only the class and its subclass can access the field / method.

There's a fourth visibility, called the "package visibility" which takes place when no keyword is specified : the field / method can be accessed within the same package. This visibility isn't used very often.

Here's a little example :

```
public class A {
    public int var2; // this is a public variable
    protected int var3; // this is a protected variable
    private int var1; // this is a private variable

    public void test() { } // this is a public method
    protected void test3() { } // this is a protected method
    private void test2() { } // this is a private method
}
```

You can see in my little example, that my class also has a visibility, the exact same rules as for fields and methods are used, only for instantiation instead of accessibility.

In your case, there's two different solution to allow access to your field from the subclass :

1. declare the field as `public`, `protected` or without visibility (ie package visibility)
2. declare the field as `private`, and add a setter, getter or others access methods. This is the preferred method and it is called encapsulation.

Since this is probably a homework, I won't provide code to you, it will be a good exercise to write it yourself.

PS: I know that encapsulation is a little more than just what I explained, but dropping the name like that won't hurt the OP ;)